# firebase/php-jwt throws Signature verification failed error on every scenario in PHP 7.4

Tags: php, firebase, jwt, token, php-7

I've installed firebase/php-jwt as described in the repo.
In composer file.

```
"firebase/php-jwt": "~5.5.1",
"paragonie/sodium_compat" : "~1.19.0",
```

In my PHP file

```php
$jwtSecret = "785373b58697498280905a4c9382ce8b4c9382ce8bsds234sd785373b58697498280905a4c9382ce8b2324c9382ce8b234sds24";
$payload =[
   "item1" => 1900,
   "item2" => 1800,
];

$jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $jwtSecret, 'HS512');
print_r(['jwt' => $jwt]);


$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt,$jwtSecret, array('HS512'));

print_r(['decode' => $decoded]);
```

It throws `Signature verification failed` error. but [JWT.IO](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJpdGVtMSI6MTkwMCwiaXRlbTIiOjE4MDB9.uYXmqLMpirOY3LikQq3-CgmobkfGpeRAsSKJPdaMWkrbIkjazWYy2Io2iWQhA4kD_6rh9zmzfyfRIirILcLfGg) says  Signature Verified by the same `$jwtSecret` without base64 encoded.

I almost tried every other solutions from SO, but nothing seems working. Can you please find what's wrong here?

Comment: What happens if you attempt to decode like the documentation suggests - `$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, new Key($jwtSecret, 'HS512'));` ?

Comment: @Darren It is the same result.